# Download file to local folder using Capybara running tests on grid

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, selenium-grid, download

I'm having trouble with tests that download/export a CSV only when running against the grid.  When the tests run locally, they are fine.  It's because of the way we download and check the file:

```
module DownloadHelpers
  TIMEOUT = 10
  PATH    = Rails.root.join('tmp/downloads')

  def downloads
    Dir[PATH.join('*')]
  end

  def download
    downloads.first
  end

  def download_content
    wait_for_download
    File.read(download)
  end

  def wait_for_download
    Timeout.timeout(TIMEOUT) do
      sleep 0.1 until downloaded?
    end
  end

  def downloaded?
    !downloading? && downloads.any?
  end

  def downloading?
    downloads.grep(/\.part$/).any?
  end

  def clear_downloads
    FileUtils.rm_f(downloads)
  end

end
```

When I run tests against the grid, the browser on the node is trying to save the file to itself and not to the machine that is running the test.  Has anyone run into this issue...and hopefully solved it?

Comment: if you can save the file onto the grid node, maybe you can then send it to your server using RestClient or something.

Comment: Have you tried that?  Do you have an example?